# Adding a refresh button to jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a dataTable in my application. I am required to add a Refresh button somewhere near Search textbox within the datatable in order to refresh the table when user clicks on it. I have figured out the refresh functionality.

The thing that I am stuck with is how do I include this button within the datatable? I want to access this button `id` in my end script.

Any suggestions? Also can anyone tell what is the use of `bJQueryUI`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I simply used the following code:

```
$('<button id="refresh">Refresh</button>').appendTo('div.dataTables_filter');
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the example page for adding buttons from datatables.net

http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html

And here is the example page for sDom as mentioned by @Mike: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/dom_multiple_elements.html

Comment: @SpringLearner thanks for pointing that out. I updated it with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I was able to solve using the sDom parameter of datatables.

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/37/the-sdom-parameter/p1

Basically it allows you to place a div with an id within the datatable. I then used javascript to insert the button into that div.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a double header and use the second one for a button.

bJqueryUI allows you to use jQueryUI themes or the theme roller. So if you add the jQueryUI before you initialize datatable you could use that style instead of the default one.